# Hide vertical axis with facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I plot this without the information to the left of the graphs? I.e "wt" and its numbers should not be visible. Graphs must remain intact. Information under and to the right of the graphs should be visible.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt))
p <- p + geom_point()
p <- p + facet_grid(cyl ~ ., scales="free_y")
p
```

From reading other questions and answers here on SO, I suppose theme_blank() could be used, but not sure where to place it with facet_grids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
p + scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL) + ylab("")
```

**Edit:** The solution above changes scales back (ignores "free" option). How about this?

```
p + theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
            axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

Comment: PS: I had to verify that I'm a human being to post this.. any idea why? :)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but how can I keep the "free_y"-setting?